# Why does 'continue' behave like 'break' in a Foreach-Object?

Tags: powershell, foreach

If I do the following in a PowerShell script:

```
$range = 1..100
ForEach ($_ in $range) {
    if ($_ % 7 -ne 0 ) { continue; }
    Write-Host "$($_) is a multiple of 7"
}
```

I get the expected output of:

```
7 is a multiple of 7
14 is a multiple of 7
21 is a multiple of 7
28 is a multiple of 7
35 is a multiple of 7
42 is a multiple of 7
49 is a multiple of 7
56 is a multiple of 7
63 is a multiple of 7
70 is a multiple of 7
77 is a multiple of 7
84 is a multiple of 7
91 is a multiple of 7
98 is a multiple of 7
```

However, if I use a pipeline and `ForEach-Object`, `continue` seems to break out of the pipeline loop.

```
1..100 | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ % 7 -ne 0 ) { continue; }
    Write-Host "$($_) is a multiple of 7"
}
```

Can I get a `continue`-like behavior while still doing ForEach-Object, so I don't have to breakup my pipeline?

Comment: Here is a page with lots of commands to use with `foreach`: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Windows_PowerShell_1.0_Looping_with_the_for_and_foreach_Statements#Continuing_for_Loops

Comment: Found a decent explanation and sample here... http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2015/04/27/understanding-break-continue-return-and-exit.aspx

Comment: the link is dead and the other links don't really explain this. Could you find it again please?

Answer (score 238, accepted):

Simply use the `return` instead of the `continue`. This `return` returns from the script block which is invoked by `ForEach-Object` on a particular iteration, thus, it simulates the `continue` in a loop.

```
1..100 | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ % 7 -ne 0 ) { return }
    Write-Host "$($_) is a multiple of 7"
}
```

There is a gotcha to be kept in mind when refactoring. Sometimes one wants to convert a `foreach` statement block into a pipeline with a `ForEach-Object` cmdlet (it even has the alias `foreach` that helps to make this conversion easy and make mistakes easy, too). All `continue`s should be replaced with `return`.

P.S.: Unfortunately, it is not that easy to simulate `break` in `ForEach-Object`.

Comment: From what OP is saying apparently `continue` can be used to simulate a `break` in `ForEach-Object` :)

Comment: @ Richard Hauer Such a `continue` will break the whole script, not just `ForEach-Object` where it is used.

Comment: I voted on this several years ago, yet I keep forgetting this every 8-12 months. ‍♂️Maybe now when I comment on this, it will hopefully stick oo.

Answer (score 32):

Because `For-Each` object is a cmdlet and not a loop and `continue` and `break` do not apply to it.

For example, if you have:

```
$b = 1,2,3

foreach($a in $b) {

    $a | foreach { if ($_ -eq 2) {continue;} else {Write-Host $_} }

    Write-Host  "after"
}
```

You will get output as:

```
1
after
3
after
```

It is because the `continue` gets applied to the outer foreach loop and not the foreach-object cmdlet. In absence of a loop, the outermost level, hence giving you an impression of it acting like `break`.

So how do you get a `continue`-like behaviour? One way is [Where-Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/Where-Object) of course:

```
1..100 | ?{ $_ % 7  -eq 0} | %{Write-Host $_ is a multiple of 7}
```

Comment: Using the Where-Object cmdlet is a good suggestion. In my actual case, I don't think it makes sense to make the multiple lines of code preceding my if statement into a single long line of hard to read code. However, that would work for me in other situations.

Comment: @JustinDearing - `In my actual case, I don't think it makes sense to make the multiple lines of code preceding my if statement into a single long line of hard to read code.` What do you mean?

Comment: @manojlds maybe he thinks that your one line solution is "hard to read", at least for me is completelly the contrary. The pipeline way to do things is really powerfull and clear and is the correct approach for simple things like that. Writing code in the shell without taking advantage of that is pointless.

Comment: In my case this was the right answer, add a where condition to filter out the objects that I would be doing a continue or return on so that I don't need to process them in the first place. +1

Comment: I really like the suggestion of `Where-Object` because it allows you to print an alternate message or log it while still executing the rest of your code so you don't have to loop through a list multiple times, while it sounds like `continue` or `return` immediately drop out of the loop, so if you had a couple conditions you wanted to compare against you would have to build up a gnarly block of combined `if` statements or loop through the list of objects a couple different times.

Answer (score 4):

A simple `else` statement makes it work as in:

```
1..100 | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ % 7 -ne 0 ) {
        # Do nothing
    } else {
        Write-Host "$($_) is a multiple of 7"
    }
}
```

Or in a single pipeline:

```
1..100 | ForEach-Object { if ($_ % 7 -ne 0 ) {} else {Write-Host "$($_) is a multiple of 7"}}
```

But a more elegant solution is to invert your test and generate output for only your successes

```
1..100 | ForEach-Object {if ($_ % 7 -eq 0 ) {Write-Host "$($_) is a multiple of 7"}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is kind of a hack, but you can wrap your block in a loop that will execute once. That way, `continue` will have the desired effect:

```
1..100 | ForEach-Object {
    for ($cont=$true; $cont; $cont=$false) {
        if ($_ % 7 -ne 0 ) { continue; }
        Write-Host "$($_) is a multiple of 7"
    }
}
```

Comment: Frankly, that is ugly :) And not just an hack because instead of the foreach-object, you could have as well used a foreach loop.

Comment: @manojlds: 1..100 is for illustration only.
do {} while($False) works just as well as for loop and bit more intuitive.