# continue statement confusing in powershell, looks like break statement

Tags: powershell, syntax, continue

My code looks like:

```
1..10 | % {
    $i=$_
    10..20 | % {
        if ($_ -gt 12) {
            continue
        }
       Write-Host $i $_
    }
}
```

Why the output is:

```
1 10
1 11
1 12
```

It seems the `continue` statement in PoweShell is not different with other language, why PowerShell is designed like this?

If I change the `continue` to `return`, then I get the expect result.

Comment: You have no loop to continue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does continue behave like break in a Foreach-Object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760013/why-does-continue-behave-like-break-in-a-foreach-object)

Answer (score 2):

As PeterSerAI pointed out in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37781563/continue-statement-confusing-in-powershell-looks-like-break-statement/37782240#comment63031022_37781563), you *don't use a loop* in your code, you are instead using the [Foreach-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113300) cmdlet which is [different](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/07/08/getting-to-know-foreach-and-foreach-object/).

Just use a `foreach` loop instead:

```
foreach($obj in 1.. 10)
{
    $i = $obj
    foreach($obj2 in 10 ..20) {
        if ($obj2 -gt 12) {
            continue
        }
       Write-Host $obj $obj2
    }
}
```